# Access - Field Validation Rule - Limit to 1 language

Tags: ms-access

I'm currently trying to place a validation rule on a text field which is supposed to contain several English words as well as numbers and no other languages or characters. I've tried setting the validation rule as:

```
Is Null or Not Like "*[!a-z]*"    
Is Null or Not Like "*[!a-z0-9]*"
Is Null or Not Like "*[!a-z]*" Or Not Like "*[!0-9]*"
```

Which results in limiting the field to a either a null or a single word. As the field requires several words and numbers none of those solutions were appropriate. I've also tried simply removing the asterisk at the beginning of the block:

```
Is Null or Not Like "[!a-z]*"
```

This produces a result that is very close to what I need. However, some foreign (primarily Chinese) characters are showing up in the fields when data is imported.

Is there a reliable way to limit a field to only English words with numbers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your third approach is closest. Just add a space to your list of allowed characters:

```
Is Null or Not Like "*[!a-z0-9 ]*"
```

Note that character return and line feed characters are disallowed, so importing content with newline characters will fail.

Comment: Ah! Adding that space was definitely a big improvement. Thank you!

Comment: One additional question: Why would adding an exclamation mark to the allowed characters allow in Chinese characters?  "Is Null or Not Like "*[!a-z0-9! ]*"

Comment: Eh... that's an invalid like expression, an exclamation mark is a relevant character and should be escaped. But escaping characters in like expressions is a different question and should be asked as such.